# google protobuf - PB_BYTES_ARRAY_T(n) - what is the use of .size field?

Tags: c, protocol-buffers, nanopb

My protobuf file is

```
message Msg{
    // User Authentication data as bytes. 
    bytes MsgData = 1 [(nanopb).max_size = 2048];
}
```

When I generate the **C** API, the relevant parts are:

```
#define PB_BYTES_ARRAY_T(n) struct { pb_size_t size; pb_byte_t bytes[n]; }

/* Struct definitions */
typedef PB_BYTES_ARRAY_T(2048) Msg_AuthenticationData_t;

/* Maximum encoded size of messages (where known) */
#define Msg_size  2051
```

**QUESTION**

Who sets the field `pb_size_t size`? And why isn't it set in the macro somehow?

Since the size of the payload is known - **2048** in this case - shouldn't `pb_size_t size` always by **2048**?

Note: I understand that **2051** is for the encoded size and **2048** is for the size of payload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since the size of the payload is known - 2048 in this case - shouldn't pb_size_t size always by 2048?

When you set `(nanopb).max_size = 2048`, it is the maximum size. The actual size of the data can be anything from 0 to 2048 bytes.

The `.size` field should be set by your code prior to encoding, and it will be set by `nanopb` when decoding a protobuf message.

If the length of the data is always the same, you can additionally set `(nanopb).fixed_length = true`. Then the `.size` field is not generated. Any incoming messages with length different than `max_size` will cause `pb_decode()` to return an error.

Comment: When I send the buffer, do I also need to send the `.size` field separately i.e. as another parameter into the function that reads it? `void func(char * buf, int num_bytes_written)`?